# How do i give a specific href link in HTML and code?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, hyperlink

While making a website using bootstrap 4, I have inserted the following HTML code

```html
<form action="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQN-pnXPaVg" target="_blank">
  <button>Start</button>
</form>
```

Here i have given a link to a SPECIFIC video but it is redirecting to the main page of youtube. I have rechecked the link but nothing is working. Please help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the link and click share

This link works

```
<form action="https://youtu.be/pQN-pnXPaVg" target="_blank">
  <button>Start</button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/28gewda5/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the following way instead of utilizing form just to open a youtube video.

In this, you will be using `.btn` and `.btn-primary` classes to make hyperlink look like a button.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQN-pnXPaVg" target="_blank">Button</a>
```